# SQL Joins : How can i get latest record from 2nd table (one to many relationship)

Tags: sql-server, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables

1.Product  table having columns

- prod_code
- alert_limit
- prod_description

2.Daily_data table having columns

- prod_code
- used_today
- date
- stock_left

How should i join these two tables to get recent records of each product on the basis of date ?
I have tried

```
SELECT p.*, d.*
FROM product p
JOIN daily_data d ON (p.product_code = d.prod_code)
LEFT OUTER JOIN daily_data d2 ON (p.product_code = d.prod_code AND 
(d.date < d2.date OR d.date = d2.date AND d.prod_code < d2.prod_code))
WHERE d2.prod_code IS NULL;
```

but the above is giving me one recent row of the last product added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

row_number()

```
select * from 
(
select *
     , row_number() over (partition by table2.prod_code order by table2.date desc) as rn
from table1 
join table2 
  on table1.prod_code = table2.prod_code 
) tt 
where rn = 1
```